# Userform: ComboBox and TextBox updating total price

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am a beginner with VBA and trying to learn. I need help making my userform perform the following actions. ComboBox5 is a part number from sheet2 column A, TextBox2 displays the price on sheet2 column B based on part selected in ComboBox5. I need help trying to make ComboBox4 (Quantity) multiply against TextBox2 (Price) and display the total in TextBox3. Currently my code will multiply in Textbox2 however I need it to display the price in TextBox2 and the total in Textbox3. Here is my current code:
Here is my sample code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()
Me.TextBox2.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.ComboBox5.Value, 
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").CurrentRegion, 2, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox4_AfterUpdate()
If ComboBox4.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
TextBox2.Value = ComboBox4.Value * TextBox2.Value
End Sub`
```

Comment: Try `TextBox3.Value = ComboBox4.Value * TextBox2.Value`

Comment: `TextBox2.Value = ComboBox4.Value * TextBox2.Value` should be `TextBox3.Value = ComboBox4.Value * TextBox2.Value`. Note the change from `TextBox2.Value = ` to `Textbox**3**.Value = `. As a note, it would be much easier to read your code if you changed the control names from the default names to names that actually said what they were (`PriceText` instead of `TextBox2`, for instance). Why make it harder on yourself than it has to be by using generic control names?

Comment: Solved. Thank you for the tips and advice; good points. Once I added the code into ComboBox4: TextBox3.Value = ComboBox4.Value * TextBox2.Value it worked as intended.